# Confused about subspaces, how do I picture them geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I'm a visual learner and I'm having trouble intuitively understanding subspaces. Our professor defined a subspace as a non-empty set closed under linear combinations. However, I'm having trouble picturing this.

Are subspaces just lines, planes, and n-dimensional spaces?

Can subspaces be finite? I.e. can a subspace in $R^3$ be a cube with dimensions 10x10x10?

Comment: a cube isn't a sunspace because if you scale he points in it you get a larger cube.  A cube isn't finite, though. Still, the only finite subset of a real vector space that is a suspace is the origin.

Comment: I think you meant to ask whether a subspace can be *bounded*. The answer is no, except for the case of $\{ 0 \}$, because if $x \neq 0$ is in the subspace then $\{ n x \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an unbounded sequence in the subspace. Or geometrically, every nontrivial subspace contains a line (not a line segment, an entire line).

Comment: "Are subspaces just lines, planes, and n-dimensional spaces?" Yes . But ensure that the lines and planes pass through zero. Also, it is very useful to know when the union and intersection of subspaces will result in another subspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, They're just lines,planes,and n-dimensional spaces.

But you have to be aware of that those n-dimensional spaces must pass through n-dimensional origin,

E.g $\mathbf{x_1,x_2}$ are two vector in a subspace, then for any $c_1,c_2$ the linear combination $c_1\mathbf{x_1}+c_2\mathbf{x_2}$ must be in that subspaces too, and if you take $c_1,c_2$ to be both zeros ,then you have the origin.

And I don't think the subspace can be finite , since you can choose arbitrarily  large $c_i$ to stretch your vectors to a infinite "long" vector , Unless the vector you have is null vector (then you have the trivial case, which is the origin)

Comment: Not to be picky, but you cannot get an infinitely long vector in a real vector space. Also, there is a finite subspace -- the trivial space, {0} (as mentioned above).

Comment: yeah, the trivial case is somehow "finite". But i don't quite understand why we cannot get an infinitely long vector in a real vector space. thanks

Comment: A vector can only be scaled by an element from a field, usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ none of whose elements are infinite in magnitude.  The vector space goes on infinitely but it has no single element which is infinite.